# Convert string into ISO date python

Tags: python, mongodb, postgresql, date, psycopg2

I'm using `postgresql`.On it I have data that I have to use on python. 
One table field contains a date. It looks like this:

[image]

On my python script using `psycopg2` I'm geting results, when I get the date it is saved as a string on mongodb

```
"created" : "2016-06-16T19:53:43.776456"
```

My code looks like this:

```
query = "SELECT name, created FROM user;"
cur.execute(query)
user_data = cur.fetchall()
for user_info in user_data:
    user_json = {
       'name': user_info[0],
       'created': user_info[1]
    }
```

I want to convert this  `"created" : "2016-06-16T19:53:43.776456"` into  `"created" : ISODate("2016-06-24T09:08:09.333Z")`, but I don't know how to convert it in the right format. Please help!

Comment: `select json_build_object('name', name, 'created', to_char(created, '"ISODate"(YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.MS"Z")')) from user;`

Comment: From where should I import ` to_char`

Comment: `to_char` is a PostgreSQL function. In my example above the query produces ready to use JSONs. You can use it in the way you provided like: `query = "SELECT name, to_char(created, '\"ISODate\"(YYYY-MM-DD\"T\"HH24:MI:SS.MS\"Z\")') FROM user;"`

Comment: executing this gives this error `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.` why can it be ?

Answer (score 1):

IMO you does not need to specify `ISODate` when you store the data into the MongoDB.

Python code (fragment):

```
cur.execute("select name, created from tt_user;")
data = cur.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print(row[0], row[1])
    mdr = {
        'user': row[0],
        'created': row[1]
    }
    mongo_db.tt_user.insert_one(mdr)
print("Done.")

print("Check data in MongoDB");

for row in mongo_db.tt_user.find():
    print(row)
```

and its output:

```
Load data from PostgreSQL into MongoDB...
('user1', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 13, 26, 28, 632436, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)))
('user2', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 13, 26, 28, 632739, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)))
('user3', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 13, 26, 28, 632751, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)))
('user4', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 13, 26, 28, 632757, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)))
('user5', datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 13, 26, 28, 632762, tzinfo=psycopg2.tz.FixedOffsetTimezone(offset=180, name=None)))
Done.
Check data in MongoDB....
{u'_id': ObjectId('5773a254afd34b43d76aa792'), u'user': u'user1', u'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 10, 26, 28, 632000)}
{u'_id': ObjectId('5773a255afd34b43d76aa793'), u'user': u'user2', u'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 10, 26, 28, 632000)}
{u'_id': ObjectId('5773a255afd34b43d76aa794'), u'user': u'user3', u'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 10, 26, 28, 632000)}
{u'_id': ObjectId('5773a255afd34b43d76aa795'), u'user': u'user4', u'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 10, 26, 28, 632000)}
{u'_id': ObjectId('5773a255afd34b43d76aa796'), u'user': u'user5', u'created': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 29, 10, 26, 28, 632000)}
```

And in the MongoDB console:

```
> db.tt_user.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773a254afd34b43d76aa792"), "user" : "user1", "created" : ISODate("2016-06-29T10:26:28.632Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773a255afd34b43d76aa793"), "user" : "user2", "created" : ISODate("2016-06-29T10:26:28.632Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773a255afd34b43d76aa794"), "user" : "user3", "created" : ISODate("2016-06-29T10:26:28.632Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773a255afd34b43d76aa795"), "user" : "user4", "created" : ISODate("2016-06-29T10:26:28.632Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5773a255afd34b43d76aa796"), "user" : "user5", "created" : ISODate("2016-06-29T10:26:28.632Z") }
>
```

So it is behavior of the client software, not the storage issue. Just save  then data as datetime.

PS: Thank you that you forced me to to install MongoDB finally :)

Comment: thank you for your answer. 
When I print a item from results i get this `("abc", '2016-06-15T16:58:19.465608')` so my date there is treated like string, for that when i do `'created': row[1]` it is saved like this `"created" : "2016-06-16T19:53:43.776456"` so for that for me is not working like this

Comment: @Egzona Provide `user` table DDL (create script).

Comment: @Egzona I thing that you stores the date/time values as string instead of `datetime` type. Try to convert them when you create the JSON object.

Comment: It seems like I can't change it, but can I convert it  from string to ISO date in python like this: `string_date = "2016-06-16T19:53:43.776456"
    datetime_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(string_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    var = { "date" : datetime_date}
    return  var`

Comment: @Egzona Exactly, but change the pattern according to your value (`T` missed): `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f"`

Comment: @Egzona BTW it was my second Python program and my first experience with MongoDB :o) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
query = "SELECT name, created FROM user;"
```

by this

```
query = "SELECT name, 'ISODate(\"' || created || '\")' FROM user;"
```

The query will return the well formed string you want to store as `created`.

Comment: This is saving still date as a string, just like this `"created" : "ISODate(\"2016-06-17T14:30:35.906396\")"`

Comment: I'm not used to psycopg2 and python. You need to escape properly quotes and double quotes in order to get `SELECT name, 'ISODate("' || created || '")' FROM user;` assigned to `query` var and provide this as argument to `execute()`